# When deleting GRUB from UEFI partition, should some entires from <EFI_partition>:/boot/ also be deleted for it to be a clean removal of GRUB & linux?

Tags: arch-linux, partition, dual-boot, grub, uefi

I read from [this](https://askubuntu.com/questions/429610/uninstall-grub-and-use-windows-bootloader) thread the instructions to delete a GRUB entry from the EFI partition. The top answer talks about using `diskpart` in windows(in the case of a dual boot) to navigate to, and delete the GRUB directory in question present in `Y:/efi/` (where Y is the drive letter of the UEFI partition). Should some files in `Y:/efi/boot/` also be deleted for a clean removal of GRUB or the OS(assuming it to be Linux) the person wants to remove?

I am a newbie in these fields, I do remember that when installing something like Linux, we mount the EFI partition after we format it at `/boot/efi`; and that's why I am asking this. I might be totally off the mark here. But I just want to be clear about this as my EFI partition is very small and hence I really don't want any residual files from previous installed to take space in there.

I currently have arch-linux installed, which I want to remove temporarily due to circumstances.

Comment: The EFI System Partition does not really contain boot entries, just files. The "entries" are in the UEFI firmware variables, which contain references to the boot files on the ESP, e.g. the Grub boot loader.

Comment: @JohanMyréen, so no more files related to linux now resides on the EFI partition after deletion of grub directory in /efi?

Comment: This depends on how the Linux system was installed. If `Y:/efi/boot` is the Linux `/boot` directory containing files like `vmlinuz*`, then these files can also be deleted to save space. My point in my previous comment was that the Grub entry in the UEFI boot entry list should also be deleted (using e.g. `efibootmgr`), otherwise it points to a nonexistent file.

Comment: If only Windows, /EFI/Boot/bootx64.efi is normally a copy of Window's /efi/Microsoft/Boot/bootmgfw.efi . You may need to restore that as grub install makes it a copy of /EFI/Ubuntu/shimx64.efi. That is a fallback or drive entry. See also:http://askubuntu.com/questions/63610/how-do-i-remove-ubuntu-in-the-bios-boot-menu-uefi &
https://askubuntu.com/questions/429610/uninstall-grub-and-use-windows-bootloader

Comment: @JohanMyréen I understand now, and oldfred 's comment seems to point this out as well.